# Application stuck in prepared state on WebLogic ServerAdministration Console 12c

Tags: weblogic

I have deployed an application on weblogic 12c and all the deployment successful while I am trying to run the application the application status changed to "start running" after a while it changed to prepared.Its not showing state as Active can some one help me please.In log files also there is no errors are showing

Comment: Looks like application is failing to start. Check server stdout logs for any exceptions. You can enable deployer debugs to get verbose logging. Without any exception it's impossible to find out the cause.

Comment: And please describe the steps you followed to deploy and start the application